# Display initials of name on condition angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this data in variable

```
Names : "Amit Singh, Kumar Anand"
Names : "Ashish Singh"
```

this can be single name or multiple names seperated by commas "James, Anand, xyz,..."
In for loop

```
<div *ngFor="let user of Info">
{{ (user.Names != null && user.Names.length>0) ?
                                        (user.Names |
                                        slice:0:1)
                                        : '' }}
</div>
```

Here we get output only `A` but i want `AS` if comma is not present otherwise if comma is present (i.e. multiple names are there) i want to display `M` in place of first name and last name

Any solution Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "I want to display `M` in place of first name and last name"?

Comment: @BernardBorg If names contain` Names : "Ashish Singh"` single name then it should display `AS` otherwise if `Names : "Amit Singh, Kumar Anand"` multiple names with comma seperated then directly `M` to be displayed

Comment: So "Amit Singh, Kumar Anand" just becomes "M, M"?

Comment: No it should be single `M`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you want it in 1 line;

```js
user.Names.split(",").length === 1 ? 
    user.Names.trim().split(" ").map(x => x[0])
     .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
  : 'M'
```

Comment: thanks i tried this getting error  `{{  user.Names.split(",").length === 1 ? user.Names.trim().split(" ").map(x => x[0]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)  : 'M'  }}`
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 106 in

Comment: Parser Error: Conditional expression `user.Names.split(",").length === 1 ? user.Names.trim().split(" ").map(x => x[0]).reduce((acc, curr)`  requires all 3 expressions at column 114 can you pls check

Comment: Works on my end - check for missing brackets

Comment: `{{ user.Names.split(",").length === 1 ? user.Names.trim().split(" ").map(x => x[0]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr) : 'M' }}` using this code brackets are there but still getting error